# Custom page password recovery

Tags: password

I'm building a custom page for password recovery...

I get the action  "login_form_lostpassword" to redirect the custom page.

```
function new_lost_password_form()
{

    if ( 'GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $this->redirect_logged_in_user();
            exit;
        }

        wc_get_template('page-templates/lost-password-form.php');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('login_form_lostpassword', 'new_lost_password_form');
```

When i try recover a password everything works fine, But when an error occurs as the input blank the wordpress redirect to the default recovery page.

This happen why the wordpress reads the wp-login.php first...

As i will make to wordpress override the content of recovery page wich is in wp-login.php ?

The block must override is:

```
case 'lostpassword' :
case 'retrievepassword' :

    if ( $http_post ) {
        $errors = retrieve_password();
        if ( !is_wp_error($errors) ) {
            $redirect_to = !empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : 'wp-login.php?checkemail=confirm';
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
            exit();
        }
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['error'] ) ) {
        if ( 'invalidkey' == $_GET['error'] ) {
            $errors->add( 'invalidkey', __( 'Your password reset link appears to be invalid. Please request a new link below.' ) );
        } elseif ( 'expiredkey' == $_GET['error'] ) {
            $errors->add( 'expiredkey', __( 'Your password reset link has expired. Please request a new link below.' ) );
        }
    }
```

in the file wp-login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add your own action before any errors are returned, and if there is an error, redirect back to your page and display the error

```
add_action( 'lostpassword_post', 'smyles123_check_for_errors' );

function smyles123_check_for_errors( $errors ){

    if ( $errors->get_error_code() ){
        // REDIRECT BACK TO YOUR PAGE TO SHOW ERRORS
        // You can probably just append the error to the URL you redirect back to, but you need to set $redirect_to value
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
        exit();
    }

}
```

You could also just create your own function to handle the password reset and just copy the code from `wp-login.php`

There's plenty of tutorials online to do this:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-3-password-reset--cms-23811

You can also look through the code on this plugin I created a while back that handles almost everything in relation to `wp-login.php` ... should have plenty of code information on handling custom errors, redirects, even rewrites:

https://github.com/tripflex/wp-login-flow

Comment: I'll read and study this material you sent, thanks very much! 

Thanks for answer!

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget to accept it as the answer (if this was what you needed)